# Send 1 email to each person with all their codes

Tags: powershell

I need to write a script that sends a single email to each person.
That email will have unique codes for the person.
Each person can get any number of codes.

The data looks like this

```
Email,Codes
Email@dom.com,213
Email@dom.com,999
Email2@dom.com,111
Email2@dom.com,123
Email2@dom.com,643
Email2@dom.com,809
Email2@dom.com,722
Email3@dom.com,013
```

I think the script will go something like this.

```
#get the data
$PeopleAndCodes = Import-Csv C:\temp\PeopleCodes.csv

#Count how many groups of unique people
[array]$CountOfPeople = $PeopleAndCodes.email | Group-Object -noelement | Select-Object Count

#Loop through unique people
$Index = 0;
while ($Index -lt $CountOfPeople.count) {
    $Index++

#THIS BELOW EXITS BEFORE GETTING THROUGH ALL THE CODES FOR ONE PERSON
    [int]$DCodes = 0
    foreach ($DCodes in [int]$CountOfPeople[$DCodes].count) {
        $DCodes++

        Write-Host $DCodes DCODES
        Write-Host $CountOfPeople[$DCodes].count CountOfPeople
        Write-Host $PeopleAndCodes[$DCodes].codes
    }
}
```

The problem is that my 2nd loop stops as soon as number of unique people is reached and then moves to the next person.

I don't understand why the 2nd loop is not going through the codes and then to the next person?

Comment: I believe in your inner `foreach` loop, you wanted to use `0..[int]$CountOfPeople[$DCodes].count` tho the code seems an overengineering and likely can be simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, I would make some small tweaks to your code and we can get it there.

First, instead of indexing through the array, let's select all of the unique e-mails from the list of codes.

```
$uniqueUsers = $PeopleAndCodes | select -Unique Email
```

Next, we can `foreach` loop our way through the list of `$uniqueUsers`, and for each, find any matching codes for them.

```
foreach($uniqueUser in $uniqueUsers){
    $thisEmail = $uniqueUser.Email

    $matchingCodes = $PeopleAndCodes | Where Email -Match $uniqueUser.Email |
         Select-Object -ExpandProperty Codes
```

Now we have within this loop a `$thisEmail` var that holds the email address of the user, and then an array of all of the matching codes for the user, called `$matchingCodes`.  We don't need to index through these either.  In fact that second loop was likely causing the issue, as *there are more items in the list than unique users*.

Your limiting condition was the number of unique users, *not the number of items in the list.*

So, to avoid confusion and get the desired output, just remove that second loop entirely since it isn't helping us.

```
        Write-Host "Person - $thisEmail"
        Write-Host "Person has $($matchingCodes.Count) codes"
        $matchingCodes -join ","
```

Gives an output of

```
Person - Email@dom.com
Person has 2 codes
213,999
--------------------
Person - Email2@dom.com
Person has 5 codes
111,123,643,809,722
```

#### Completed Code

```
$PeopleAndCodes = Import-Csv C:\temp\PeopleCodes.csv
$uniqueUsers = $PeopleAndCodes | select -Unique Email

foreach($uniqueUser in $uniqueUsers){
    $thisEmail = $uniqueUser.Email

    $matchingCodes = $PeopleAndCodes | where Email -Match $uniqueUser.Email | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Codes

    Write-Host "Person - $thisEmail"
    Write-Host "Person has $($matchingCodes.Count) codes"
    $matchingCodes -join ","

    Write-Host "--------------------"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that while above is the best answer. In the comments is another answer that works with my original code as well.

```
#get the data
$PeopleAndCodes = Import-Csv C:\temp\PeopleCodes.csv

#Count how many groups of unique people
[array]$CountOfPeople = $PeopleAndCodes.email | Group-Object -noelement | Select-Object Count

#Loop through unique people
$Index = 0;
while ($Index -lt $CountOfPeople.count) {
    $Index++

#This loops through each person and gets their code(s)
    [int]$DCodes = 0
    foreach ($DCodes in 0..[int]$CountOfPeople[$DCodes].count) {

        Write-Host $PeopleAndCodes[$DCodes].email
        Write-Host $PeopleAndCodes[$DCodes].codes
        $DCodes++
    }
}
```